# In my iOS app, how can I know the device orientation when viewDidLoad is called?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {

        NSLog(@"PORTRAIT");

    } else {

        NSLog(@"LANDSCAPE");
    }
}
```

but it seems that `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` returns 0 so I can't know in which orientation the device is at that moment. How can I know it ?

Comment: why so important to know the orientation in the `-viewDidLoad` method? it would be easier to check it in the `-viewVillAppear:` and set the content's bound to the orientation here...

Comment: Yea, you shouldn't use -viewDidLoad for that. Use -viewWillAppear: or even better use -viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: with viewWillLayoutSubviews LANSCAPE keeps being written in the console and the app freezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using

```
UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation]
```

This from:

[iOS Developer Library: Responding to Orientation Changes in a Visible View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)

> The window adjusts the bounds of the view controller’s view. This causes the view to layout its subviews, triggering the view controller’s viewWillLayoutSubviews method. **When this method runs, you can query the app object’s statusBarOrientation property to determine the current user interface layout.**

Answer (score 0):

You can check the orientation of device like this

```
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
{
NSLog (@"Device is in Portrait Mode");
}
else
{
NSLog (@"Device is in Landscape Mode");
}
```